# Need to enable button when text is entered in the edit boxes

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I would like to use 2 TEdit item and a button for this. How can I check if all the Edit have some text value. After that i want to activate a button.

Main form Onshow event:
Btn1.Enabled:=false;

if Edit1.text + Edit2.text have value then btn1.enabled:=true ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you [using actions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Action_Lists)? If not, you should consider it.

[Add a `TActionList` to your application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_Up_Action_Lists) if you don't already have one. Next, add a `TAction` to it. Set the action's properties so it resembles the button. (I.e., set the caption, and move the button's `OnClick` event handler to the action's [`OnExecute`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBasicAction.OnExecute) handler.) Assign the button's `Action` property to refer to the new action object.

Finally, handle the action's [`OnUpdate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBasicAction.OnUpdate) event. In it, enable or disable the action as needed. The button (and any other controls you later choose to associate with the same action) will be [updated accordingly](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Updating_Actions).

```
procedure TSteveForm.ButtonActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TAction(Sender).Enabled := (Edit1.Text <> '') and (Edit2.Text <> '');
end;
```

This looks very similar to handling the `OnChange` events of the edit controls, but its differences become apparent when the scenario changes:

1. If you add or remove edit controls, you only have to change this one procedure to ensure the button is enabled correctly. If you're handling `OnChange` events, you need to change the procedure *and* assign it to each new control's `OnChange` property.
2. Not all controls have a convenient `OnChange` event that lets you know when something has changed. Actions' `OnUpdate` events relieve you from having to know exactly when an update is appropriate. They run while the program is idle and on demand.

Comment: Beat me to an answer before I could get back to edit mine. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Edit1.OnChange` event, and set it to also handle `Edit2.OnChange`. The event handler code is simple:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Btn1.Enabled := (Edit1.Text <> '') and (Edit2.Text <> '');
end;
```

Comment: Personally I'd sooner see actions used for this. It makes code be more declarative.